# Find AKS Cluster ip on vnet

Tags: azure-aks

I want to access my AKS cluster from my vnet resources using the internal ip and have the external access ip restricted. Is there a w3ay to get the internal Vnet IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You will find the private IP in the Private DNS Zone `privatelink.<region>.azmk8s.io`.

I would suggest if you create a private cluster to use public or private FQDN (DNS) instead of using the IP to access your cluster: `<CLUSTERNAME>.privatelink.<region>.azmk8s.io`.

You can also configure the AKS that the public FQDN will be resolved to the private IP. There are several options available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters#configure-private-dns-zone).